# How to the retrieve the username value from login frame to another frame with java?

Tags: java, authentication, data-retrieval

When the user login, the login frame close and open another frame where I need the user login details to get the others details. My prepareStatement & resultSet are already set at the top. Still a newbie in java

login action listener

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(( ActionEvent ae) -> {
    if (ae.getSource().equals(btnLogin)) {

    DB_connection db_connection = new DB_connection(); 
    String username = username_login_txtf.getText();
    String password = password_login_txtf.getText();

    try {   

     String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_profile as up WHERE up.username=? AND up.user_password=?";

     preStatement = db_connection.connect().prepareStatement(sql);

     preStatement.setString(1, username);
     preStatement.setString(2, password);

     res = preStatement.executeQuery();

     boolean login = false;

        while(res.next()) {         
             if(res.getString("username").equalsIgnoreCase(username) && res.getString("user_password").equalsIgnoreCase(password)) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginPanel, "You have Logged in!");

        login = true;

        fr.dispose();
        Main_menu.main(null);
        break;

        } ...
```

My other frame where i need to retrieve that specific user login data

```
    btnSearch.addActionListener(( ActionEvent ae) -> {
        if (ae.getSource().equals(btnSearch)) {

      // Right now i am getting the username value from another text field that I have set in this form but I want to retrieve that value directly form the login frame
            String get_username = username_profile_txtf.getText();

                DB_connection db_connection = new DB_connection(); 

                try{

                    preStatement = db_connection.connect().prepareStatement("Select * from user_profile where username = ?"); 

       // here I need the user login username from the login form
                    preStatement.setString(1, get_username);

                    res = preStatement.executeQuery();

                    if (res.next()){

                    String username = res.getString("username");
                                username_profile_txtf.setText(username);

                        ...
                        }

                    preStatement.close();
                    res.close();

                } catch(SQLException ex){

                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                } finally {
                        db_connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does your login frame create and show the other frame?  Or are they both created from some other class?

Comment: when the user login, the login frame close and open another frame which has a button where i need the user's username

Comment: When the user log in, pass the username to the second frame as an attribute. Either through a constructor or a setter.

Comment: Could you explain with an example for clarity

Comment: Sure.  Right now you're probably creating your second frame like this: `MySecondFrame secondFrame = new MySecondFrame()`.  You could add a parameter to the constructor so you can pass the username in.  Such as `MySecondFrame secondFrame = new MySecondFrame(username);`  You would need to add a matching constructor such as `public MySecondFrame(String username) {this.username = username;}`

Comment: Another example using setters after creation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412498/pass-values-entered-in-one-jframes-text-field-as-an-input-parameter-in-other-jf

Answer (score 0):

Follow the *MVC*-pattern.

Create a model-layer which is merrily a bunch of stupid DTO classes enhanced with some infrastructure to register Listener on changes withing the model. 
Create a store for username/password there.

Pass the model as dependency to any GUI class, so that all work against the same instance. (Do not use the <strike>Singelton Pattern</strike> to access the model.)

Comment: what? I still a beginner could you explain in more details

Comment: I think wikipedia is a better resource for long explanations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller